# How to fix filter using crystal reports

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, printing, crystal-reports

I have a working code in my other print, but this does not do at all, please help me fix my filter codes n crystal reports by number

```
ReportDocument crypt = new ReportDocument();
// crystalReportViewer2.SelectionFormula = "{PatientData.PatientIDD}='" + textBox5.Text + "'";
string query = "SELECT * FROM PatientData WHERE PatientIDD='" + textBox5.Text + "'";

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, cn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "@PatientIDD");
crypt.Load(@"C:\Users\RANDOM\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CrystalReport2.rpt");
crypt.SetDataSource(ds);

crystalReportViewer2.ReportSource = crypt;
ds.Dispose();
```

The error is:

Object is not an ADODB.RecordSet or an ADODB.Record. Parameter name: adodb

Comment: What is the error message? The clearer detail you give the better response. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Create Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for ideas to improve your question.

Comment: Object is not an ADODB.RecordSet or an ADODB.Record.
Parameter name: adodb

Comment: The issue is not with Crystal Report, it is with your dataset fill. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776364/system-argumentexception-object-is-not-an-adodb-recordset-or-an-adodb-record. Are you sure to use"@" before table name?